# Laravel: How to get Many-to-many association in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my sports application I would like to  have a page where team members are listed under under each team in order of their "active" status.

The three models involved are teams, users, and groups. The "groups" are like a status field for each user. Eg, inside a team some players are in the "active" group and some are inactive.

Users can belong to many teams and many groups (so both relationships are many to many). Groups belong to teams (many to one). The three models are set up with these relationships.

So far, I have a simple controller that looks up a member's teams and fetches those teams for the view:

```php
class HomeController extends Controller
{
  public function showHome()
  {
    if (Auth::check())
    {
      $user = Auth::user();
      $teams = $user->teams;
      return View::make('indexUser', compact('teams'));
    }
    else
    {
      return View::make('index');
    }
  }
}
```

In my indexUser view, as a simple test, I can do the following to list the users and add an "*" next to inactive users:

```php
@foreach ($teams as $team)
  @foreach ($team->groups as $group)
    @foreach ($group->users as $user)

      {{$user->first_name}},

      @if($group->name == 'Inactive')
        (inactive)
      @endif
      ,
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The above code outputs this, which is on the right track:

> Steven , Wellington , Kirsten , Stacy , Brent , Delbert , Nelle ,
>   Johnpaul , Nora , Nathanael , Effie , Elva , Ophelia , Carlotta ,
>   Dameon , Arnoldo , Emelia , Natalia , Monte (inactive) , Chris
>   (inactive) ,

However, that adds 6 queries to the page and it doesn't give me control over the ordering. Eg, it's pure chance whether the inactive members are listed before or after the active users.  My hunch is that the bulk of the querying should be done in the controller, but that is where I hit my mental block.

Any tips on how I should approach this in the most efficient way?

Comment: Does `$user = Auth::user()->with('teams.groups.users');` work? Then they are eager loaded

Comment: That sounds promising. However, if I use that statement, the following line, "$teams = $user->teams;", triggers an error: "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$teams".

Do I need to change how I send the models to the view?